# Laravel Vendor\bin files are empty

Tags: php, laravel

everyone, I've been working on my project, and then I needed to install extra package on laravel, so when I tried so, I got an error, and then I discovered that files in vendor\bin directory are empty, I don't really know why so, but does anybody have any idea how to recover it, or what I have to do?
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCD83.jpg)

Comment: please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to asking questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Answer (score 2):

Delete the composer package lock file, and then a simple
`composer install` would work.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help, it gives same error about vendor\bin directory

Comment: I faced the same problem. removed the `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file and ran `composer install` and I was good to go.